# decompressing git objects with zlib

Tags: python, git, object, zlib

I decompressed three git objects with this Python script:

```
import zlib

filename = '/path_to_file' 
compressed_contents = open(filename, 'rb').read() 
decompressed_contents = zlib.decompress(compressed_contents) 
print(decompressed_contents)
```

for these three objects, I get these three outputs:

```
b'tree 32\x00100644 file\x00\xe6\x01\xe5\x92\x8e\xcc.\xc5\xbe\t\x91{\xe9\x92:\x85\xc4\x89\xe9H'

b'commit 196\x00tree 2b32fe41c7f8c21d5010fb59a59bcce42b2b3ab5\nauthor author <author> 1643729123 +0100\ncommitter author_email <author_email> 1643729123 +0100\n\nadd hello\n'

b'blob 6\x00hello\n'
```

In the git documentation ([git probook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects%5Bgit%20probook%5D%5B1%5D)) they say that git add a null byte at the end of the object header which is `\u0000`. But when I decompress those objects with zlib, `\u0000` are replaced by `\x00`.

- So, what does git really store in those files, `\u0000` or `\x00`?
- Does this script output the `raw content` of git objects?

Comment: `\u0000` and `\x00` are the same thing: `print(repr('\u0000'))`

Comment: is it the same thing or is it interpreted the same way?

Comment: They are not the same thing, confusing them is dangerous, as it pretends that "encodings" don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

`\x00` is stored. Or more precisely: a single byte with the value 0 (or `0x00`, if you want) is stored.

`\u0000` is the Unicode NUL character, a.k.a [U+0000 NUL](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+0000). The `\u` escape mechanism is a common way to represent Unicode characters, even though it's usually limited to 4 hex digits (which means it can't represent Unicode code points outside of [the BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), such as U+1F600 ).

Why are these two used interchangeably? Because in most character encodings `\u0000` is actually encoded as `0x00`. Specifically most 8-bit encodings as well as UTF-8 follow this practice.

Note that it's still important to distinguish the two things, because one is a *character* (that will often be mapped onto a byte) and the other is a *byte value* (that can often be interpreted as a character).

Comment: so what is actually stored in the file is 0x00 and zlib interprets it as \x00?

Comment: Both `0x00` and `\x00` are just notations that describe a single byte with the value 0. What is stored inside of files are bytes, not their representation. So both `0x00` and `\x00` are just notations that we humans use to talk about those values, but they represent the same thing (8 bits, all of which are 0). `0`, `\x00` and `0x00`, as well as `\0` are just more-or-less widely ways to describe this same value. Create a hexdump of those files (after decompressing them, of course) using something like `hd inputfile` and it'll probably help you understand the distinction.

Comment: zlib only deals with bytes. It _does not care_ what they represent. The input may be encoded in many ways. (As noted, in UTF-8, U+0000 is encoded as a single zero byte.) All zlib guarantees is that what you get from decompression is exactly what was compressed, byte for byte.